# Cannot load external json with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have some strange issue with requirejs. I am using json [plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) and when I type

```
define(function (require) {
    list = require('json!http://localhost:9025/app_dev.php/dog/get-races');
```

everything works, unfortunately when I tried

```
define(function (require) {
   var  url = 'json!'.concat('http://localhost:9025/app_dev.php/dog/get-races');
   list = require(url);
```

then I got message

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "json!http://localhost:9025/app_dev.php/dog/get-races" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

Do you have any idea why it happened?

------------------ answer & solution ---------------------
Eran H. pointed me to proper place (Thank you). When using sugar syntax then require.js scans function body for require('string') unfortunately require(variable) does not match the pattern. Solution in easy, I created "proxy" file where I didn't use sugar syntax.

```
define([url], function (list) ....
```

Comment: I think this might be related to your problem:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes

. Read this part: "This form will use Function.prototype.toString() to find the require() calls..."

Comment: Do we talk about the r compiler or running it in the browser without compilation?

Comment: Running in the browser